# Dynamic schema __tableargs SqlAlchemy MarshMallow Python Flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, marshmallow

I have three database instances (SIACPracti, SIACMercatti and SIACDelivery) within the same server called fsoft, a table that is repeated in each instance called siactloc  the fields (ciacodigo,usrcodigo,locdodigo, ) when I perform the sql from where I call them as follows

select * from SiacPracticasa.dbo.siactloc

select * from SiacMercatti.dbo.siactloc

select * from SiacDelivery.dbo.siactloc

**I would like to be able to have the code to have an api that brings me all the records through a table in a specific instance when I send for a parameter in the header called prefix "SiacPracticasa.dbo" or "SiacMercatti.dbo" or ""SiacDelivery.dbo""**

Currently this is my code of how I have mapped my table and how with an api I can bring the records but from a single instance

```
from app.extensions import db
from app.extensions import ma

class Siactloc(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'siactloc'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'SiacPracticasa.dbo'}
    ciacodigo = db.Column(db.String(2), primary_key=True)
    usrcodigo = db.Column(db.String(10), primary_key=True)
    loccodigo = db.Column(db.String(3), primary_key=True)

    usrflagmodificaarticulo = db.Column(db.Integer)

class SiactlocSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Siactloc
```

This is the code of my api

```
# {
#   "user": "­v}xg",
#   "password": "I4bªszuj",
#   "seleccion": 
#       {
#           "cliciaciacodigo": "01",
#           "cliciacianombre": "PRACTICASA",
#           "clicianonBD": "SiacPracticasa",
#           "cliciarutaBD": "fsoftapptest.futuresoft-ec.com,14666"
#       }
# }
@bp.route('/get_localidad', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def get_localidad():
    data = request.get_json() if request.is_json else None
    cliciausu = encriptar( data['user'])
    seleccion = data['seleccion']
    ciacodigo =seleccion['cliciaciacodigo']

    results = db.session.query(
        Cgblocal.locdescri, Cgblocal.loccodigo
    ).join(
        Siactloc, Siactloc.ciacodigo == Cgblocal.ciacodigo
    ).filter(
        Siactloc.ciacodigo == ciacodigo, 
        Siactloc.usrcodigo == cliciausu, 
        Cgblocal.locstatus == 'A'
    ).distinct().all()

    # Serialización de los resultados con Marshmallow
    # local_schema = CgblocalSchema()
    local_schema = CgblocalSchema(many=True)
    output = local_schema.dump(results)

    return jsonify(output)
```

```
def create_dynamic_siactloc(clicianonBD):
    class DynamicSiactloc(Siactloc):
        __table_args__ = {'schema': clicianonBD}
return DynamicSiactloc
```

```
This was the result
```

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't place **table_args** on an
inherited class with no table.